# Счётчик посещений страницы с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Что-то счётчик работает через раз.
На странице где нужен счётчик вшиваю вот такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var views = <?php echo $article->id ?>;
</script>
```

Потом есть вот такой общий скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if (typeof views == "number") {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/countviewspage",
        type: "POST",
        data: views,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
 }
});
```

Ну и на сервере по этому айди (views), происходит выборка записи статьи (страницы). У каждой статьи есть колонка отвечающая за количество просмотров, эта колонка инкременируется и новое значение записывается в БД. Сам php код без ajax работает нормально. А вот ajax выдаёт ошибку 500.

Понятно, что чаще всего 500 в консоли вылетает по вине серверного скрипта, но без ajax php код функционирует нормально. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы логи посмотрели? Пользуйтесь Dev Tools которые в каждом броузере есть, что бы посмотреть, что отправляете. А так же покажите код `/countviewspage`.

Comment: @E_p , в логах отправляется номер айди. В принципе ниже уже помогли. Но сейчас попробую ещё штуку добавить чтобы юзать скрипт во всех нужных разделах, придётся много чего добавить. Господи, хоть бы работало -=)))

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, проблема в параметре data ajax-запроса.
Этот параметр предполагает массив, а не целочисленное значение. 
Попробуйте исправить на

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/countviewspage",
    type: "POST",
    data: {views:views},
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

и на сервере извлекать значение из пришедшего $_POST['views']

Comment: И вправду утро вечера мудренее. Фиг знает, за работало при {views: views}, но ведь изначально я так и делал, просто тоже не работало и я стал просто views отправлять. Хотя я уже там столько перепробовал, что возможно при моём {views: views} другие ошибки были. А сейчас норм, спасибо!

Comment: Пользуйтесь вкладкой Networks в инструментах разработчика Chrome, где видно всю информацию о запросах. Там было видно, что при отправке вашего варианта, просто views, в запросе не уходили никакие данные ($.ajax просто не понимал, что ему делать с одиноким числом и не отправлял его), а при изменении на массив сразу видно, что к запросу начали добавляться "Form Data" с нужными данными.